# aChartEngine get all value of all point in the graph

Tags: android, achartengine

hi mate i use a chartengine to do graphic in my app. I want to implement the function "save graph" and "Load graph" , I think that i have to save in a file all value of point example:
1,1
2,2
14,5

and in load graph i read from file and i do parsing and add the point saved in the graph. But How can get all point in the graph to save it on file ?

```
 for(int i=0;i<this.mCurrentSeries.getItemCount();i++)
   { xi=getPOintX(i);yi=getPOintY(i);
```

but there is function in this lib that allow to get all x and y value of graph ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVE IT:
mCurrentSeries.getX(i)) FOR X VALUE